# Selenium in a docker container and windows integrated authentication

Tags: windows, selenium, authentication, containers

We are on a mission to run our acceptance tests from a selenium container running different browsers in their own containers and we have set things up so minimal config changes are necessary when testing on a local machine or a remote one triggered by continuous integration.

The stumbling block I have hit is that the site under test is authorised through windows authentication and the chrome container is effectively running as a different machine, which means that when WebDriver serves up the site it is prompted with a log in box.
So far I have run into dead ends with every technique I have used to get round this.

I can't send the credentials in the uri as many older posts suggest - just doesn't work. I can't use AutoIt to populate the auth window as the window is in a container and that runs in linux. Finally had no joy trying to proxy from one server to test server, for what ever reasons the credentials are not recognised that I set up in the proxy (using for example cntlm proxy tool).
Is this mission impossible or is there any way round this?